# Big O of unknown algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, time, big-o, time-complexity

I got an unknown algorithm that I need to calculate the time complexity for (Big O).
The only thing that I know about the algorithm is how long it takes to finish its calculations for a given number of values.
Just to make it clear, the algorithm is taking a number and returning the time taken when using that number.

Using the time taken and the numbers given for that time, I get a nearly straight line if I make a plot of the time taken against the numbers given. The line fits well to the complexity of `O(n log n)`. The problem is still that even if the line does fit, I can't prove that the complexity really is `n log n`. so How can I prove the complexity?

Here are some values:

```
time: 0.008  number of elements: 4000
time: 0.100  number of elements: 40000
time: 0.1200 number of elements: 400000
time: 1.4000 number of elements: 4000000
```

Comment: You can't. You could estimate it with some certainty if you have a few more data points and error bars.

Comment: There is only one way to get the time complexity in such cases. And you have already described the method. There is no other definite method. However to be sure, you can use more points to confirm that the complexity indeed is O(NlogN).

Comment: Your estimate is only as good as your data, so you can only say something about how the algo behaves given data of the kind you have given it, e.g. O(n log n) given normal-distributed random data etc.

Comment: What kind of inputs does the algorithm takes? Is it just a single list with values? Do the values themselves affect performance? Do you know what the algorithm does? You should try different executions of the algorithm with different input values but same length. And definitely you need much more samples... depending on the accuracy of the estimate you want to obtain.

Comment: I have tried whit allot more values, and the resulting curve still fit somehow to the one given by nlogn

Comment: If you drop out notion of BigO here, you get simple regression analysis. You have independent variable(s) (number of elements, you may consider other as well) and one dependent variable (time). You need to establish one or more hypothesis (formulas) about their relation, find appropriate coefficients and then estimate an error. Among all your hypothesis, the one with least error is the most close to real relation. Read more about regression models for details.

Comment: @Carsten is correct, there are not enough points. Although a straight line fits these points very well, it's clear from the [plot](http://www.image-share.com/ipng-2493-105.html) that 4 points are inadequate especially when the x values are separated by orders of magnitude.

Comment: It is very hard to determine if an algorithm is linear or linearithmic. The order of growth of **log(n)** is so slow that the errors due to the experimentation can give you false positives in both cases. Finding if an algorithm is **either O(n) or O(n log n)** is a much simpler quest since the difference with **O(log n)** and **O(n²)** are significant and can be detected using a very small set of data points. Needless to say that the more points you have, the more accurate you can determine an algorithm's complexity. From what I understand, you can have as many points as you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are right: you can't *prove* the complexity, and you need more points to model it empirically. This is shown by the plot of your current data.

[image]

If you get more data, one thing you could do to investigate it is a [log-log plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-log_plot), plotting the log of time t against the log of number of elements n. This gives you a straight line with gradient p if your relationship is of the form: t = n^p, as illustrated below with some simulated data. The black points are for a y=x^2 relationship, the green for y=x, and the red for y=x*log(x) is somewhere inbetween.

[image]

If you think it's an nlogn relationship, you could simply plot t against nlogn, and you should get a straight line. Regression analysis is certainly possible, but if you look at your current data, you actually get a very good straight line fit from a linear regression  (shown on the first plot above), and I certainly wouldn't say that it's linear on that basis.